# Missing .dll under Modules, causing a "no symbols loaded" error. C# Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, debugging, dll, visual-studio-2015, module

I cannot share the code in question however, my issue stems from a specific project under my solution. It does not load the dll into the modules when debugging. This causes a "No symbols loaded" error when putting in a dot for debug. The -pdb and .dll are both visible in the obj/debug folders. Colleagues running exactly the same code, does not get the error and they can also debug this specific project.

Anyone got any suggestions on what to do?

I have searched around for hours and consulted several senior colleagues without any solution in sight. In short, I need the .dll to load as a module (this also leads to this project not updating for me until the day after, when our solution gets built on our server - creating all manner of issues for my code and debugging possibilities).

Because I do not see the .dll in the modules window, I cannot attach it or force it to load symbols. I have not found any way of manually add the .dll to be loaded.

Comment: Have you checked the path to the DLL in the project? Have you seen this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582864/why-is-loaded-dll-missing-in-visual-studios-modules-list

Comment: Yes, I had read and tried those solutions before. That sadly did not solve it.

*Update: Since, I have found what caused the issue. Apparently there was an .xml file pointing wrong that had somehow remained even though the entire project was removed and later restored. 

Thank you for your input though.

Answer (score -1):

Found the issue. I had a .XML file that was pointing me wrong. Also, the solution had reverted back to a state where it only loaded one of the projects, thus missing the one that wasn't loading.

Comment: Since it has been resolved, you could mark your solution as the answer.